# Каждый раз при запуске приложения выводится запрос на доступ к аккаунту ВК

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Каждый раз при запуске приложения выводится запрос на доступ к аккаунту ВК. Но так быть не должно. Где что-то упустил?

```
MainActivity.class
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.OFFLINE};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VKSdk.login(this,scope);
    }



Application.class
public class Application extends android.app.Application{
VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
        if (newToken == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    VKSdk.initialize(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Программа делает ровно то что вы написали:

> При запуске активити показать экран входа в аккаунт.

Вам надо это делать только для незалогиненных юзеров. Т.е как то так:

```
if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) VKSdk.login(this,scope);
```

Comment: Согласен, что написал, то и выполнялось. Просто я думал, что единожды получив доступ, ВК у себя сам где-то отмечает и повторно не выводит. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Ан нет, так не работает. Окно доступа не выводится, но стало быть и не происходит далее ничего. В onResult далее не переходит

Comment: @ШураБалаганов, мой ответ отвечаем на вопрос почему у вас каждый раз запрос авторизации происходит. То, как вы его обрабатываете - к вопросу не относится. Ответил как дальше надо в другом ответе.